# Issue with resizing windows using an Application Compatibility shim

Tags: windows, vb.net, windows-10, compatibility, shim

I'm trying to run a legacy VB6 application on Windows 10. I'm using creating an .sdb shim file which detects the application's .exe using the Compatibility Administrator tool found in the Windows ADK. Whenever the .exe runs, the screen resolution is resized to a specific resolution. When the .exe stops, the resolution returns to normal.

The Compatibility fixes I'm using are "ForceDisplayMode" with parameters to display at the legacy app's old resolution. And also "ForceTemporaryModeChange" which will revert the screen resolution back to normal.

One problem I'm having is that when the application is open, if I close my laptop lid and reopen it, the .sdb stops working (windows doesn't log out). If I log out, the old resolution is maintained as expected. I'm trying to figure out if there's an option to maintain the .sdb's resolution, or if this is an oversight on Microsoft's end?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in the off chance that anyone has this incredibly obscure problem in the future, the solution was apparently to disable tablet mode on Windows 10 1809. That solves the .sdb shim being undone by closing the lid on my SP3/SP6s.

Edit: Ok, turns out that was not the solution. It was just coincidence, so I've uncheckmarked this answer. We had an image that didn't have this problem but then later images reverted this behavior. Still don't know why this occurs.

Edit 2: I still don't know why this occurs but I have a few observations that may help someone. I'm on Windows 10 LTSC Version 1809 Build 17763.615. It seems to have to do with specifically putting the SP6 to sleep via flipping up the keyboard. If you sleep by Windows > Power > Sleep or pressing the power button or letting the SP6 go to sleep on its own, the SDB is correctly maintained. Another odd observation is that if you sleep via the 3 ways listed above but then flip up the keyboard, the SDB is cancelled.